# Deploying HTML file on Heroku?

Tags: html, heroku, deployment, hosting

I have a simple project consisting of three files which are the HTML, JavaScript and CSS files. I did everything on heroku which they said but then I got an error regarding some buildpack.
So I used this particular answer to fix it. [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40134660/16232116)

then when did the command
`git push heroku master`
I didn't get any error but when I did open app from Heroku, There was a 404 error and description was nginx. I don't why this is happening but please tell me where am I going wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant host  static website on heroku the github pages will be better suitable

the best workaround is to trick the heroku that we are hosting the php app

convert name`index.html` to `home.html`

create `index.php` and write `<?php include_once(“home.html”); ?>` on it

add `composer.json`
and push to heroku